# How to make a Webbot to automate Google Calendar?

Tags: php, automation, google-calendar-api

I want to make a Webbot that can read my emails and extract information related to stuff like submissions, assignments, tests etc and then automatically add a reminder according to the submission date on Google Calendar. 
I've got through the first part, my PHP Webbot can extract information I want from the emails automatically but I don't know how to automate the Google Calendar part.
Please guide me through this.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe any issues you have had with the Google calendar api

Answer (score 0):

1. You should study on **Appium** for automating mobile app (http://appium.io/)
2. [There are lots of resources on web](http://ezyautomation.blogspot.com/2017/11/prepare-windows-pc-for-automated-your.html)